# Error Using Variable as a Tag in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I have a question about tags in Terrafrom. I have this variables, and I'd like to use the Transit variable description name as a tag in my main.tf file. How do I go about it?

```
#VPC CIDRs
variable "All_VPCs" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    Dev_VPC = {
      ip = "10.0.3.0/24"
      instance_tenancy = "default"
    }
    Transit_VPC = {
      ip = "10.0.4.0/23"
      instance_tenancy = "default"
      description = "Transit_VPC"
    }
  }
}
```

I used this, but it didn't work.

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "Transit_Internet_Gateway" {
  vpc_id = var.All_VPCs.Transit_VPC

tags = {
    Name = "${var.All_VPCs.Transit_VPC.description}" + " Internet_Gateway"
  }
```

Comment: I went ahead and answered your question, because the error in your code looks obvious, but for future reference **never** post a question about an error you are getting without including the actual error message in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate strings in Terraform with a `+` operator. The correct method of doing this is to use string interpolation (which you are already partially doing):

```
tags = {
    Name = "${var.All_VPCs.Transit_VPC.description} Internet_Gateway"
  }
```